# Creating vector of all individual correlation

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

I am trying to create a vector of all correlation of variables for each cross sectional unit, using `dplyr` approach returns an error as variables needs to be numeric.

I dont know how to solve it

What I need to end up with is a dataframe, that contains correlation between `crmrte` variable and all other explanatory variables BUT at cross-sectional level.

I need to specify code below:

```
cors <- crime %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  summarize(cor = cor(crmrte, prbarr))
```

---

**Update:**

As [suggested by Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59101743/680068), generalizing code above to be *automatic* I did this:

```
cors <- crime %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(names(crime)[4:ncol(crime)]), funs(cor(crmrte, .)))
```

But not sure if it is right approach

Comment: That's a lot of `i`'s in there...

Comment: Maybe a `for` cycle is not a very good approach, I am just trying to do it automaticaly so I dont have to write each variables

Comment: Why are you unsure that it is correct??

Comment: some values seems to be a bit weird - not sure if it is due to a dataset or my code

Comment: What do you mean *your code*?

Comment: Don't copy-paste answers into your question and present it as yours.

Comment: I meant your code - sorry, my code because previours example was on cross-sectional data, ths example is on panel data

Comment: I suggest you get a small example, do the calculations manually and then check them against the code to cross reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `summarise_at` along with `vars()` which automatically quotes the names

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
 group_by(cyl) %>% 
 summarise_at(vars(names(mtcars)[6:10]), funs(cor(mpg, .)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>  # A tibble: 3 x 6
>     cyl     wt   qsec      vs     am     gear
>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1     4 -0.713 -0.236  0.0488 0.536   0.339  
> 2     6 -0.682 -0.419 -0.530  0.530  -0.00949
> 3     8 -0.650 -0.104 NA      0.0496  0.0496
> ```

Comment: I provided a more speciafication with panel dataset